# Upgrading my disks to improve access performance

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, sata

My motherboard is a few years old (USB 2.0, SATA II etc), but before I make a big jump upgrading the mobo, cpu, gpu etc, I'd like to start with just upgrading my hard drives.

My SATA drive is failing. I want to replace it with a 120GB SSD drive, just for Windows, and install my data files (for apps and games), on a new SATA drive.

Do I need to find a compatible SSD drive to connect to a SATA II motherboard, or is everything I need in the box, and are there any performance disadvantages to using an external USB3 hard disk to an internal SATA disk?

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Please try and ask 1 question at a time (otherwise your question will be closed at too broad).
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

SATA-III drives are all backwards compatible with SATA-I/II,  you should have no problem installing an SSD drive in your system. All other conditions being equal, an internal SATA-II drive will outperform a USB 3.0 external drive by almost double in real world performance.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to find a compatible SSD drive to connect to a SATA II
>   motherboard, or is everything I need in the box,

You can use the same SSD on a SATA I, SATA II and SATA III controller and it will work just fine, just a tad slower. However the main speed gain from using an SSD is their random access speed, not their max transfer speeds. That means that you still gain most of the speed gain when connecting it to a SATA II port.

Bottom line: JUst buy any SATA SSD and connect it to your SATA II port.

> are there any performance disadvantages to using an external USB3 hard
>   disk to an internal SATA disk?

Yes. USB has needless overhead. So using it will be slower. If you get the right external case with supports  [USB_Attached_SCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI) then this overhead should be reduced.

Still, an internal disk just works.

And external USB disk might also work if you add drivers (not even sure if you could boot from it from windows)... So for this setup I would go for an internal SATA SSD.

This also has the advantage that you do not need to buy an USB 3 card.